# iOS How to customise the event from the Edit button in the navigation controller?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitextfield

What I have is a tableView with cells which contain in their contentViews a subView which is a textField with a tag=1. By default the textFields are setEnabled:NO . What I want is, when a user presses the Edit button, those textField to become enabled. How can I achieve that by keeping the basic functionality of the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a `UITableViewController` and the Edit/Done button is obtained from the view controller's `editItemButton`, then you need to override the `setEditing:animated:` method:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    // perform custom processing here
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) Though how can I get the currently "edited" cell(the one that get's added the red minus button), so that I can edit its contentView simultaneously?

Comment: When you enter editing mode, lots of cells may have the delete icon (red minus button). I'm not sure what you mean by the "currently edited cell". And what does this have to do with your original question?

Comment: I fixed it by using a bool variable for tracking if the app is in edit mode or not, the bool gets used by the cellForRowAtIndex method, setting the textField of the cell on or off, etc

Comment: You don't need to add a bool variable. Just use `self.editing`. The `editing` property of `UIViewController` is all you need.